# Retrofit 2 Class File issue

Tags: java, android, retrofit2, rx-java2

I am currently facing an issue when using retrofit 2 in my application.

```
public static Retrofit getClient(Context context)
{

    if (okHttpClient == null)
        initOkHttp(context);

    if (retrofit == null)
    {
        retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(CaselotREST.CASELOT_BASEURL)
                .client(okHttpClient)
                .addCallAdapterFactory(RxJava2CallAdapterFactory.create())
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .build();
    }
    return retrofit;
}
```

I get the following error when I try and compile my project.

> error: cannot access Retrofit class file for retrofit2.Retrofit not
>   found

Comment: Did you add the needed dependencies to your build.gradle?

Comment: @Phil yes, but I had to add them to the app Gradle file i only had them in my webapi gradle file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have figured it out. The issue stems from the modularity of the code base in our android application. I have many modules in my android application and each module has dependencies. The dependencies for the retrofit wherein the Webapi module but not in the main app module. To solve this was to add the following to the main gradle file

```
implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.2.0'
implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.2.0'
implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:adapter-rxjava2:2.2.0'
```

Answer (score 1):

Make Sure you have added retrofit dependency in `build.gradle` file in your project.

```
implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.5.0'
```

Comment: Dependencies in build.gradle are quite a common thing that people miss. Going great Pooja.

Answer (score 0):

If you are previously using [Retrofit 1.x](https://square.github.io/retrofit/1.x/retrofit/) and now moving on with [Retrofit 2](https://square.github.io/retrofit/), you can add this line on your gradle file

```
implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.5.0'
```

also make sure that you have the needed permission on your `AndroidManifest` file

```
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

If you are interested on using `RXJava` with `Retrofit` you can check this [link](https://medium.com/mindorks/rxandroid-retrofit-2fff4f89fa85) for tutorial.

```
    //example 
    Gson gson = new GsonBuilder()
            .setLenient()
            .create();

    Retrofit build = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(BuildConfig.BASE_URL)
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(gson))
            .client(unsafeOkHttpClient)
            .build();
```

Cheers if this helped you.

Answer (score 0):

If using RxJava2 with retrofit, you would need something like this.
Add dependencies for gson & retrofit, and if you're using rxjava observable in your retrofit api service something the adapter imports.

```
/* retrofit, gson */
implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.4.0'
implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:adapter-rxjava2:2.3.0'
implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.4.0'
implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:3.8.1'
implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-scalars:2.4.0'
```

Then your builder would look something like this:

```
 Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(Constants.BASE_API_URL)
            .addCallAdapterFactory(RxJavaCallAdapterFactory.create())
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .client(okHttpClient)
            .build();
```

Where,

```
okHttpClient = new OkHttpClient.Builder().build();
```

And you could then create the service,

```
retrofit.create(RetrofitAPIService.class);
```

Where your RetrofitAPIService would hold the API implementations something similar to this:

```
@Headers("Content-Type: application/json")
@POST("v1/login/")
Observable<ApiResponse> userLogin(
        @Body String body
);
```